# React + Webpack Dev Server: page is NOT interactive when visiting http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

When I visit http://localhost:8080, everything works as expected including hot reloading.

However, when I visit http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/, nothing seems to work; can't type into the input components, can't scroll, etc.

It's almost like the page is frozen. This just started happening after a fresh npm install. It wasn't a problem previously.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const PATHS = {
  app: './src/index.js',
  html: './src/index.html',
  dist: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
};

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    javascript: PATHS.app,
    html: PATHS.html
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.dist,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: PATHS.dist
  },
  eslint: {
    emitWarning: true
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loaders: ["eslint-loader"],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: "file?name=[name].[ext]"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ["react-hot", "babel-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

Here's my file layout:

```
-dist
-node_modules
-src
 - components
 --index.js
 --index.html
--webpack.config.js
```

Comment: can you share your `webpack.config.js` file so that we can check it and also it will be better if you share your code folder hierarchy ?

Comment: Added. I've now tested on a different platform and the same issue exists.

It's really weird because I've been using localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/ the entire time while creating my app and it was always fine before.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your `public path` like below

```
module.exports = {
 entry: {
  javascript: PATHS.app,
  html: PATHS.html
 'webpack/hot/dev-server', // For hot style updates
 // The script refreshing the browser on none hot updates
 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',

},
output: {
  path: PATHS.dist,
  publicPath: '/webpack-dev-server/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. One thing I should add, when I visit http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/, everything does render. It's just that all interactivity is gone. That is, I can't even highlight text with my cursor.

At this point, I'm sure the culprit is related to the iframe WDS injects under that URL.

Comment: i have edited the code on entry point, can you give it another try